# Firebase access within GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication

It seems that the latest sdk `com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:3.0.0` relies on creating threads for most calls, e.g., `com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference`

This is a problem when using GAE since it promptly throws an Exception:
`servlet java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")`

Are we suppoed to just use the JVM sdk (`com.firebase:firebase-client-jvm`) instead?

The instructions aren't so clear and it seems like the legacy website is the only one where we can get the secret. The new website gives us the .json file.

Has anyone had any success with using the new v3 version with GAE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just tested.

As with the 2.x SDKs, you can work around the threading limitation by using manual scaling.

While the Cloud guide on using Firebase with GAE is a bit outdated, the section on [manual scaling](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio#configuring_the_app_engine_backend_to_use_manual_scaling) should still be useful to help you through this.

More on ThreadManager [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager#class-threadmanager).

Comment: This didn't work. I get the following error when I set manual scaling to 1: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
at com.google.firebase.database.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$FirebaseThreadFactory.newThread (DefaultRunLoop.java:13)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.doIdleCheck (PersistentConnectionImpl.java:1098)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.<init> (PersistentConnectionImpl.java:266)

Comment: Which sounds like a great Stack Overflow question!

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem and discovered the cause in this [blog thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/CZYPteFV1Xw).

When adding dependences, I had included `appengine-java-sdk` but overlooked `appengine-api-1.0-sdk`.  Adding it eliminated the exception.  The full dependencies block is:

```
dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.48'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:3.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.48'
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Include the JSON file in the "Resource Files" of appengine-web.xml.
Example:

```
<resource-files>
  <include path="/**.xml" />
  <exclude path="/feeds/**.xml" />
</resource-files>
```

See the link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appref#resource_files .
"The files that listed in the  element are accessible by the application code using the filesystem. These files are stored on the application servers with the app as opposed to how static files are stored and served.".

Comment: Please include relevant code / sample from the link referenced in the answer.  External links may become invalid down the line and this answer will become irrelevant at that time.  Please try to provide as much explanation as possible in the original answer along with link at the bottom as a reference.